# CppWinRT wont generate headers for another nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, windows-machine-learning

I'm trying to get this tutorial to work: [port-to-nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/port-app-to-nuget). (Note that cppwinrt provides the `Windows.AI.MachineLearning` namespace, but for quicker releases a [different](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AI.MachineLearning/) nuget package provides the `Microsoft.AI.MachineLearning` namespace)

Apparently the C++/WinRT toolkit is meant to pick up on the Microsoft.AI.MachineLearning NuGet package and generate the appropriate headers in the Generated Files\winrt folder.

However, I've tried creating a new console app, adding the CppWinRT and Microsoft.AI.MachineLearning nuget packages with the following [code](https://topaz.github.io/paste/#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) but am still getting the following error

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winrt/Microsoft.AI.MachineLearning.h': No such file or directory

The following duplicate question doesn't help: [Cannot open microsoft.ai.machinelearning.h from NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376609/cannot-open-microsoft-ai-machinelearning-h-from-nuget-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the wrong nuget package

`Microsoft.AI.DirectML` +250k downloads instead of `Microsoft.AI.MachineLearning` +38k downloads.